# How to correctly write parameter in url when scope is array type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-scope

I created a scope and pointed it to the array type.

```
has_scope: by_industry,: type =>: array
```

And now I want to make this scope working.

I tried to pass parameter in url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/v1/find_friends?by_industry=[1,2]
```

Does not work.

How to correctly write parameter in url when scope is array type?

Comment: Try: `http://localhost:3000/v1/find_friends?by_industry[]=1&by_industry[]=2`

Comment: Yeah. It works. But why we can't pass something like that: ?by_industry=[1,2,3]?

Comment: That's how GET method parameters work. If you want to pass params like `by_industry=1,2`, you'll need to parse `"1,2"` string, and convert it into array by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass arrays through query parameters you use the key + brackets syntax:

```
?foo[]=1&foo[]=2
```

It's klunky and its ugly but thats how its been done since the early days of the web and this old CGI convention is used by Rack. The main advantage vs `foo=[1,2]` is that it is language agnostic and the params can be parsed out without interpreting the string (which is a security hazard).

Comment: This also matches how array parameters in the request body are done with form data encoding. While you could parse the param manually its just a waste of time imho.

Comment: Are there different conventions for AND vs OR? For example, if someone sent `?category[]=ruby&category[]=vue` that could be interpreted as the category should contain both ruby AND vue or either ruby OR vue. This can obviously be handled in the controller/scope, but I'm curious if there's some convention to indicate it purely via the url.

Comment: No, there is no convention since that's really a completely separate concern from what query string parameters are typically used for.